# "the rustle of tires" vs "the rustling of tires": pompous or not, is there a rule, or is it random?

Tags: grammar, nouns, gerunds

Scene: high school. Time: the present. A teacher went through a student's essay in which an out-of-the-way house in the sticks was described. It (the house) sat in the middle of a picturesque grove, and the nearest road other than the path leading up to it, was a highway - nearly a mile away. On a quiet day, when there was no wind, you could hear the cars on the highway. The student, going for the "poetic" effect, described that faint noise as "the rustling of tires." The teacher corrected it by changing it to "the rustle of tires." It is important to note that she was in no way pedantic, much less a "grammar nazi."

Question: is there a rule for favoring nouns over gerunds (and vice versa), or is it completely random?

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard tires "rustle".  (But either is valid -- "rustle" is a bit more "poetic", I would say.)

Comment: Thank you. By the way, how WOULD you describe the noise tires make on the asphalt? If they don't rustle, what DO they do?

Comment: That is a separate question, which you could 1) write up a new question, or 2) edit and tag it onto the main question.

Comment: Up close tires crunch.  From a distance they rumble or whine.